# ¿Cómo verificar el tipo de dato dentro de un CASE en SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select t1.cod_id,
     case when isnull(t1.colum_1,'')=isnull(t2.colum_1,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_1,
     case when isnull(t1.colum_2,'')=isnull(t2.colum_2,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_2,
     case when isnull(t1.colum_3,'')=isnull(t2.colum_3,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_3,
     ...
     ...
     ...
     case when isnull(t1.colum_n,'')=isnull(t2.colum_n,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_n,

from BD_1.MiTabla t1 (nolock)
     inner join BD_2.MiTabla t2 (nolock)
         on(t1.cod_id=t2.cod_id)

where t1.periodo='2009' and t1.mes='05'
```

Es una consulta que la armé para poder determinar si los datos de los registros coincidían en cada columna entre dos tablas que se encuentran en distintas bases de datos, pero que estas son idénticas en estructura y denominación, más no en el número de registros, ya que la segunda solo es un resumen del primero. De hacerlo arrojaría un `"ok"` de lo contrario un `"error"`, pero me topé con los campos que eran `null`, Estos casilleros marcaban `"error"`a pesar que su equivalente de la otra tabla también era otro `"null"`, es por eso que decido usar el `isnull` según un script que vi en internet. Pero la ejecución de este código me arrojó el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un error que apunta al `t1.cod_id` después del `select`, la razón no la sé, me sugieren en mi trabajo que primero me asegure de determinar que tipo de campo son las columnas que estoy comparando para reemplazarlas con un "*" en caso que sea cadena, y con un "-1" en caso que sea numérico, para que ese ('') no sea ambiguo o algo parecido, y después hacer la comparación.

El punto es cómo determino qué tipo de dato es cada `colum_1` antes de ponerlo en el `isnull`, tal vez se tenga que usar un `IF` aunque no veo cómo.

Cualquier sugerencia sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los tipos de datos de las columnas `t1.cod_id` y `t2.cod_id`?

Comment: Casi en su totalidad son de tipo `varchar` e `int`, y muchos campos de tipo fecha, en este caso `cod_id` es de tipo `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné este tema de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT t1.cod_id,
    case when t1.colum_1=t2.colum_1 or (t1.colum_1 is null and t2.colum_1 is null) then 'ok' else 'error' end ate_disa,
    case when t1.colum_2=t2.colum_2 or (t1.colum_2 is null and t2.colum_2 is null) then 'ok' else 'error' end ate_lote,
    case when t1.colum_3=t2.colum_3 or (t1.colum_3 is null and t2.colum_3 is null) then 'ok' else 'error' end ate_lote,
    ...
    ...
    ...
    case when t1.colum_n=t2.colum_n or (t1.colum_n is null and t2.colum_n is null) then 'ok' else 'error' end ate_lote,

FROM BD_1.dbo.MiTabla t1 (nolock) 
     inner join BD_2.dbo.MiTabla t2 (nolock)
                on (t1.cod_id = t2.cod_id)

WHERE t1.periodo= '2009' and t1.mes='05'
```

...Básicamente el problema que yo tenía era como gestionar el tema de las casillas con valor `null`. Entonces sólo tenía que asegurarme que ambas columnas sean iguales (En caso tengan valores o una de ellas sea null), o si ambas eran`null` (Aquí me aseguro en indicar que también este caso es afirmativo) para poder marcarlas como `ok`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error es porque debes castear una de las dos columnas, ya que en el `INNER JOIN` estás relacionando esas columnas.

Si  `t1.cod_id` es de tipo `varchar` y `t2.cod_id` es de tipo `numeric`, entonces debes caster `t1.cod_id` como `numeric`

Por ello, prueba cambiando tu consulta así:

```
select * t1.cod_id,
case when isnull(t1.colum_1,'')=isnull(t2.colum_1,'') the 'ok' else 'error' end colum_1,
case when isnull(t1.colum_2,'')=isnull(t2.colum_2,'') the 'ok' else 'error' end colum_2,
case when isnull(t1.colum_3,'')=isnull(t2.colum_3,'') the 'ok' else 'error' end colum_3,
...
...
...
case when isnull(t1.colum_n,'')=isnull(t2.colum_n,'') the 'ok' else 'error' end colum_n
from BD_1.MiTabla t1 (nolock)
inner join BD_2.MiTabla t2 (nolock)
on CAST(t1.cod_id AS numeric) = t2.cod_id -- nota que aquí hago el CAST.
where t1.periodo='2009' and t1.mes='05'
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error, cuando los señalo, me sombrea la línea del `select`.

Comment: @Fran.J, ¿qué tipo de dato es `t1.cod_id` y `t2.cod_id`?

Comment: son de tipo `int`

Comment: @Fran.J, ok ¿y las columnas que usas en el select `t1.colum_1, t1.colum_2...? ` creo que deberías actualizar tu pregunta añadiendo las estructuras de las tablas que usas en tu consulta select.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que son más de 280 columnas, ¿Tendría que escribir y especificar para cada uno? Justamente esa es la razón por que abrí el tema, si hay alguna forma de agilizarlo, solo quiero para el caso de int o varchar.

Answer (score 0):

> Es un error que apunta al t1.cod_id después del select, la razón no la sé...

En los comentarios indicas que las columnas evaluadas con la cláusula `WHERE` son del mismo tipo, entonces solo se genería un error ahí cuando:

```
select 1 where '1' = 1 -- ok
select 1 where '' = 1 -- ok, no origina error por PRIORIDAD DE TIPO DE DATOS
select 1 where 'a' = 1 -- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.
```

Solo en la última se genera un error, debido a que no puede convertir la letra `a` en entero `1`.

---

Revisando tu pregunta, antes de evaluar mejor convierte a un solo tipo, por ejemplo a `varchar` y puedas comparar sin problemas.

Por ejemplo:

```
declare @tabla table (
  valor1 int
  ,valor2 varchar(1)
)

insert into @tabla values 
(null, null),
(null, 'a'),
(null, '1'),
(null, ''),
(1, null),
(1, 'a'),
(1, '1'),
(1, '')

select
  valor1  
  ,valor2  
  ,case when isnull(cast(valor1 as varchar), '[NULL]') = isnull(cast(valor2 as varchar), '[NULL]') then 'ok' else 'error' end  
from @tabla
```

Donde el resultado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- [Prioridad de tipo de datos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190309.aspx)
- [Ejemplo en sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/9453)